# Python break function doesn't end while true

Tags: python, while-loop, break

Why will the break not end the while true and return to the start?

```
while True:
    print('This is a quiz')
    print('What is your name?')
    Name = input()
    print('Hello ' + Name + ', The quiz will now begin')
    import time
    time.sleep(2)
    question1 = "Question one: "
    answer1 = "True" and "true"
    print(question1)
    qanswer = input()

    if qanswer != answer1:
        print('Sorry, the answer is: ' + answer1)
        break

    if answer1 == qanswer:
            print("Correct! Here's the next question")
```

I'm pretty new to python so I assume it's just a simple misuse of the terms.

Comment: `answer1 = "True" and "true"` This is not doing what you think it is. Try printing `answer1` after you create the variable. If you want to compare the user input to two different strings, you need to compare the input against both strings. [Documentation on and](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Comment: I don't think this means what you think it means: `answer1 = "True" and "true"`.

Answer (score 5):

`break` exists the entire `while` loop.

`continue` is what you're looking for, returning to the next `while` iteration.

You can read more about control flow tools, `break` and `continue` in the official docs: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

(You also have some other bugs as others have mentioned correctly)

Answer (score 0):

use the "continue" keyword, not "break".

Answer (score 0):

```
....
answer1 = ["True", "true"]
...
if not(qanswer in answer1):
    print('Sorry, the answer is: ' + answer1)
    break
else:
   print("Correct! Here's the next question")
```